# Generated ipa not installing

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working on a project with multiple teams located in different countries. So I want to send and ipa to another team, I'm very new working with xcode.

So I finally can generate ipa to devices that were added to my list of devices on developer account.

Now the ipa that i generate only work on those devices. The way I add a device to that list is plug the device to my mac and via xcode. But now there are devices that I can't plug to my mac.

Comment: What you're looking for is probably ad-hoc distribution. Check out [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html).

Comment: Why you are not using TestFlight to distribute your app?

Comment: @TapasPal I will consider TestFlight in a near future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You donot need a physical device at hand in order to make your ipa able to be installed in that device. Ask your clients to give you their UDIDs of their iPad. Once you have them, add those UDIDs in the developer account as new devices. The way to get UDID from an iPad is as follows (send these steps to your clients):

1. Open iTunes
2. Plug in your iPad
3. Click on device name in iTunes menu.
4. Click on "Serial Number" in Summary menu.
5. Note that the Serial number will change to a long letter and number string. This is your UDID.
6. Press Command+C (mac) or Control+C (Windows) to copy the UDID from iTunes and paste it in a text file for later use.

Answer (score 1):

You just need the deices **UDID** to add into your development account so that they can install the IPA on it. 
 Ask them to get UDID using itune app.